# Post Multiple Variables (some Arrays) with Ajax to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, arrays

Was wondering if and how this is possible. I'm trying to pass multiple variables over to PHP with Jquery/Ajax. I can post multiple arrays if all of the variables are not arrays, but I can't if some of them are.

My Code:

```
<script>

var mutype;
var practiceArray = [];
var groupSizeArray = [];

function MUProvidersContinue() 
{

    variableString ='mutype='+mutype+
                    '&practiceArray='+practiceString+
                    '&groupSizeArray='+groupSizeString;

    jQuery.ajax({type: "POST", url: "musetup_auth.php", data: variableString,});

};
```

I know i need to use JSON.stringify somewhere in there, but not sure how or where.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried `datatype: json`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better is to send data as object:

```
var data = {
    mutype: mutype,
    practiceArray: practiceString,
    groupSizeArray: groupSizeString
};

jQuery.ajax({type: "POST", url: "musetup_auth.php", data: data},function(json){});
```

Comment: Thanks - this was the best way. Makes sense

Answer (score 2):

Normally when doing jQuery.ajax you want to pass an object, and it will handle stringifying for you IIRC.

So in your case:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "musetup_auth.php",
    data: {
        mutype: mutype,
        practiceArray: practiceArray,
        groupSizeArray: groupSizeArray
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var mutype;
var practiceArray = [];
var groupSizeArray = [];
var sendArray = [];

var sendArray['mutype']=mutype;
var sendArray['practiceString']=practiceArray;
var sendArray['groupSizeString']=groupSizeArray;


function MUProvidersContinue() 
{

  jQuery.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "musetup_auth.php", 
               data: sendArray
              });

};
```